# Using SUM with Joins in MySQL returns unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these tables : **customers**, **customer_invoices**, **customer_invoice_details**, each customer has many invoices, and each invoice has many details.

The customer with the ID `574413` has these invoices :

```
select customer_invoices.customer_id,
       customer_invoices.id,
       customer_invoices.total_price
from customer_invoices
where customer_invoices.customer_id = 574413;
```

result :

```
customer_id     invoice_id  total_price
574413          662146      700.00
574413          662147      250.00
```

each invoice here has two details (or invoice lines) :

first invoice `662146`:

```
select customer_invoice_details.id as detail_id,
       customer_invoice_details.customer_invoice_id as invoice_id,
       customer_invoice_details.total_price as detail_total_price
from customer_invoice_details
where customer_invoice_details.customer_invoice_id = 662146;
```

result :

```
detail_id   invoice_id  detail_total_price
722291      662146      500.00
722292      662146      200.00
```

second invoice `662147` :

```
select customer_invoice_details.id as detail_id,
       customer_invoice_details.customer_invoice_id as invoice_id,
       customer_invoice_details.total_price as detail_total_price
from customer_invoice_details
where customer_invoice_details.customer_invoice_id = 662147;
```

result :

```
detail_id   invoice_id  detail_total_price
722293      662147      100.00
722294      662147      150.00
```

I have a problem with this query :

```
select customers.id as customerID,
       customers.last_name,
       customers.first_name,
       SUM(customer_invoices.total_price) as invoice_total,
       SUM(customer_invoice_details.total_price) as details_total
from customers
       join customer_invoices
         on customer_invoices.customer_id = customers.id
       join customer_invoice_details
         on customer_invoice_details.customer_invoice_id = customer_invoices.id
where customer_id = 574413;
```

unexpected result :

```
customerID  last_name   first_name  invoice_total   details_total
574413      terry       amine       1900.00         950.00
```

I need to have the `SUM` of the `total_price` of the invoices, and the `SUM` of the `total_price` of the details for each customer. In this case I'm supposed to get `950` as `total_price` for both columns (`invoice_total`& `details_total`) but it's not the case. what am I doing wrong & how can I get the correct result please. The answers in similar topics don't have the solution for this case.

Comment: Your joins are creating multiple records (one for each detail), you will have a total of 950.00 in both of these detail records and since there are 2 rows they are being summed together. You need to include a GROUP BY to your query and this should yield the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mix normal columns with aggregate functions (for example SUM), you need to use `GROUP BY` where you list the normal columns from the `SELECT`.

The reason for the excessive amount in `total_price` for invoices is that the SUM is also calculated over each detail row as it is part of the join. Use this:

```
select c.id as customerID,
       c.last_name,
       c.first_name,
       SUM(ci.total_price) as invoice_total,
       SUM((select SUM(d.total_price)
        from customer_invoice_details d
        where d.customer_invoice_id = ci.id)) as 'detail_total_price'
from customers c
       join customer_invoices ci on ci.customer_id = c.id
where c.id = 574413
group by c.id, c.last_name, c.first_name
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6doKZk765kRkFKXCnMtKvT/1)

Comment: I see, thank you, but your query still doesn't return the correct result. It returns two rows, the first with `total_price: 250`, and the second row with `total_price: 700`, instead of just one row of `total_price: 950`.

Comment: Changing `ci.id` to `ci.invoice_id` wasn't the problem. because the column is actually `id`.

Comment: Forgot to sum the rows together. Done now.

Comment: There are many valid answers, but I'm choosing this becauase it's a faster query. Thank you all.

Comment: Actually, you do not need the outer query as you can do the SUM directly in the main query. Should be even (a bit) faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are aggregating along multiple dimensions.  This is challenging.  I would suggest doing the aggregation along each dimension independently:

```
select c.id as customerID, c.last_name, c.first_name,
       ci.invoice_total,
       cid.details_total
from customers c join
     (select ci.sum(ci.total_price) as invoice_total
      from customer_invoices ci
      group by ci.customer_id
     ) ci
     on ci.customer_id = c.id join
     (select ci.sum(cid.total_price) as details_total
      from customer_invoices ci join
           customer_invoice_details cid
           on cid.customer_invoice_id = ci.id
      group by ci.customer_id
     ) cid
     on cid.customer_id = c.id
where c.id = 574413;
```

A faster version (for one customer) uses correlated subqueries:

```
select c.id as customerID, c.last_name, c.first_name,
       (select ci.customer_id, sum(ci.total_price) as invoice_total
        from customer_invoices ci
        where ci.customer_id = c.id 
       ) as invoice_total,
       (select ci.customer_id, sum(cid.total_price) as details_total
        from customer_invoices ci join
             customer_invoice_details cid
             on cid.customer_invoice_id = ci.id
        where ci.customer_id = c.id
       ) as details_total
from customers c 
where c.id = 574413;
```

Comment: I didn't quiet get what you are doing here, but there is this error : `Unknown column 'customer_invoice_details.total_price' in 'field list'`. I changed `customer_invoice_details` to `cid` in the `select` clause, but still the same error `Unknown column 'cid.total_price' in 'field list'`

Comment: @dwix . . . Fixed.

Comment: I see, the result is correct even though the query is a bit slow. I'm still trying to understand what you did : ). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There is an error in `where cid.customer_id = c.id` there is no `customer_id` in `cid`.

Comment: @dwix . . . That was a typo.

Comment: Now I get `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` after your modification.

Comment: @dwix . . . The correlated subqueries with the right syntax should have the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

I used join against sub queries and then did a sum on the sums

```
SELECT c.id as customerID,
   c.last_name,
   c.first_name
   SUM(i.sum) as invoice_total,
   SUM(d.sum) AS details_total
FROM customers c
JOIN (SELECT id, customer_id, SUM(total_price) AS sum
      FROM customer_invoices
      GROUP BY id, customer_id) AS i ON i.customer_id = c.id
JOIN (SELECT customer_invoice_id as id, SUM(total_price) AS sum
      FROM customer_invoice_details 
      GROUP BY customer_invoice_id) AS d ON d.id = i.id
WHERE c.id = 574413
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the joining logic. The table customers is used as the driving table in the joins. But in the second join, you are using a derivative key column from the first join, to join with the third tables. This is resulting in a Cartesian output doubling the records from the result from the nth-1 join, which is leading to customer_invoices.total_price getting repeated twice, hence the rolled up value of this field is doubled.
At a high level I feel that the purpose of rolling up the prices is already achieved in SUM(customer_invoice_details.total_price).
But if you have a specific project requirement that SUM(customer_invoices.total_price) should also be obtained and must match with SUM(customer_invoice_details.total_price), then you can do this:
In a separate query, Join customer_invoice_details and customer_invoices. Roll up the pricing fields, and have a result such that you have only one record for one customer ID.
Then use this as a sub-query and join it with the customers table.